# Symfony: form field access with no sfForm object

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i'm working on a symfony project and i developed a form to upload a file and save its info to a table in my model. And didn't use the sfForm class to implement my form.
Here you have my form

```
<form name="new_file" action="<?php echo url_for('home/uploadFile');?>" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <input  value="<?php echo $codigo_maestro?>" id="master_id">
    <input  value="<?php echo $codigo_entidad?>" id="entity_id">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

So now i'm trying to access the fields of the sumbited form in my action function and don't know how :(

```
$request->getParameter('file');
$request->getParameter('master_id');
$request->getParameter('entity_id');
```

this code didn't work.
So please help me solve this! **How can i access the fields of my form from the action??**

Comment: You should use the form framework. this isn't how you do should be doing forms in symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a name to your form fields, that's the name you can access them via `$request->getParameter()`.

Comment: nice, that worked, but now, in the file input, i need to access to the file parameters, such as 'name' 'size' 'type' ... How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

finally i did this way, maybe not most elegant, but working

```
in action.class.php
   $file= $_FILES['file'];
   $filesize = $archivo['size'];
   $filetype = $archivo['type'];
   $filename = str_replace(' ','-',$file['name']);
```